# If $\|\mathbf{OA}+k\mathbf{OB} \|=1$, prove that $\text{Area}(OACB) \leq \| \mathbf{OB} \|$

Tags: vector-spaces, analytic-geometry, inner-products

OACB is a parallelogram. In other words if $\left \|\mathbf{a}+k\mathbf{b}  \right \|=1$ ($k\in\mathbb{R}$), prove that
$$\|\mathbf{a}\| \cdot \|\mathbf{b} \| \cdot \sin \theta \leq \|\mathbf{b} \| $$ where $\theta$ is the angle of the two vectors.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\| a  + kb \| = 1$ for all $k \in \mathbb{R}$, then in particular, you have $\| a + 0 b\| = \| a \| = 1$.  The inequality follows immediately since $\sin x \leq |\sin x| \leq 1$.